# How to use a variable instead of a file to output this wc command

Tags: bash

I want to read a file from a given offset until the end of that file.

I need to retrieve the number of bytes that were read during the process and also to redirect the output of the file elsewhere.

Here is my script:

```
...some stuff here...
dd if=$file bs=1 skip=$skippedBytes | tee >(wc --bytes > $file.count) >(cat - >> $file.output) | $($exportCommandString $file)
byteCount=$(cat $file.count)
rm $file.count
echo "Number of read bytes: $byteCount"
```

I would like the "wc --bytes" part to put its returned value inside a variable so I can use it after, without using a file ($file.count).

Something like:

```
dd if=$file bs=1 skip=$skippedBytes | tee >(byteCount=$(wc --bytes)) >(cat - >> $file.output) | $($exportCommandString $file)
echo "Number of read bytes: $byteCount"
```

Except that doing this, my script hangs and does not work.

Is it possible to do this and how ?

Comment: This problem was solved but is linked to the following one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67494/why-does-command-substitution-fails-in-ssh-remote-call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a small hack with redirections:

```
byteCount=$( exec 3>&1 ; 
     dd if=$file  bs=1  skip=$skippedBytes | tee -a >(wc -c >&3) $file.output |\
     $($exportCommandString $file) > /dev/null ;  3>&1   )
```

It redirects all output to 3, that you've created with exec, and then returns it back to one at the end.

You also need to redirect all output from $exportCommandString to /dev/null, otherwise it will be mixed with wc output.

All stderr will work as usual, there is no any changes.

p.s.: you can use `tee -a file` instead of `tee >(cat - >> file))`.

p.p.s.: You can't export variables from subshell, which is always created while using pipe `|` in bash or `$()`. So there is no way to make something like

```
tee -a >(VAR=$(wc -c)) $file.output
```

Comment: I corrected a small typo (missing closing parenthesis). Thank you for this complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
byteCount=$(tail -c +$skippedBytes $file | tee $file.output | wc -c)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I had expected, but it works too. Thanks