# Why does command substitution fails in ssh remote call?

Tags: bash

I have this script:

```
exportFile(){
    file=$1
    skippedBytes=$2
    exportCommandString=$3

    #This works:
    #dd if=$file bs=1 skip=$skippedBytes | ssh sshConnection 'cat - >> /remote/dir/myTarget.txt.output' > export.output 2>&1

    #This does not work:
    dd if=$file bs=1 skip=$skippedBytes | $($exportCommandString $file) > export.output 2>&1

    cat export.output
}

sshExportCommand(){
    userAtServer=$1
    targetDir=$2
    filename=$3
    echo 'ssh '$userAtServer' '\''cat - >> '$targetDir'/'$filename'.output'\'
    #Same result with this:
    #echo "ssh $userAtServer 'cat - >> $targetDir/$filename.output'" 
}

exportFile mySource.txt 9 "sshExportCommand sshConnection /remote/dir myTarget.txt"
```

When invoking it, I obtain the following output:

```
85+0 records in
85+0 records out
85 bytes (85 B) copied, 0.00080048 s, 106 kB/s
Read bytes: 85
ovh_ssh: cat - >> /remote/dir/myTarget.txt.output: No such file or directory
```

What does prevent this from working ? Is this command substitution ? Anything else I missed ?

Comment: Can you maybe strip your script down to the bare essentials for what your question is? It will greatly increase the chance for a useful answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you written in the comment code line, the following is working:

```
byteCount=$( exec 3>&1 ; dd if=$file bs=1 skip=$skippedBytes | tee -a >(wc -c >&3) -a $file.output | ssh sshConnection 'cat - >> /remote/dir/myTarget.txt.output' > export.output 2>&1 ; 3>&1 )
```

So adapt this knowledge and use this refactoring:

```
exportFile(){
   file=$1
   skippedBytes=$2
   userAtServer=$3
   targetDir=$4
   targetFile=$5
   rm export.output

   byteCount=$( exec 3>&1 ; dd if=$file bs=1 skip=$skippedBytes | tee -a >(wc -c >&3) -a $file.output | ssh ${userAtServer} "cat - >>$targetDir/${targetFile}" > export.output 2>&1 ; 3>&1 )

   echo "Read bytes: $byteCount"
   cat export.output
 }
 exportFile mySource.txt 9 sshConnection /remote/dir myTarget.txt
```

Comment: It would work, but I need export command string to be configurable and multiple. Something like this: `exportFile mySource.txt 9 "sshExportCommand sshConnection /remote/dir myTarget.txt" "sshExportCommand otherSshConnection /otherRemote/dir myTarget2.txt"`

Comment: @lauhub Sorry - that use case is not described in your question. I'm sure that you not really need it this way. Change your point of view. Duplicate transmissions can be initiated by duplicate `exportFile` calls. If you realy need it with one function, you may use a wrapper function dividing the arguments to a sequence of `exportFile` invocations.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I am gonna try this. Actually I found some workaround but was curious why this way did not work